Unable to cast object of type 'Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager' to type 'WebView.Services.WebViewNavigationManager'
Trying to move Blazor Web App to Hybrid result in exception on application start:
blazor.webview.js:1 
 Unable to cast object of type 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager' to type 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Services.WebViewNavigationManager'.

I'm pretty sure that problem in usage of @inject NavigationManager Navigation at some of blazor components (pages). I registered razor components like this:
builder.Services
    .AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

Without second part of line
builder.Services
    .AddRazorComponents();
    //.AddInteractiveServerComponents();

exception looks this way:
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment' 
while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultRazorComponentsServiceOptionsConfiguration'

Without the whole line another exception throws:
ExampleBlazorApp does not implement IComponent.

Is there an alternative to this line to register correct NavigationManager class for Hybrid Blazor App to avoid this exceptions? Any ideas?
EDIT:
Index.razor:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Main Page</PageTitle>

//plain html

MainPage.xaml, App.xaml, Routes.razor is the same as it was on creating from template.
MauiProgram contains registrations, including those I have written above.

Hi @David Levin, pls also share your razor component code which app firstly renders.

@Rena edited, Index.razor not contains anything special, but my Identity pages contains injection of NavigationManager, so I believe some wrong setup of services cause errors.

Hi @David Levin, I haven't get any issue. And for you use MAUI hybrid blazor , you should use AddMauiBlazorWebView to set up Blazor in a MAUI application.

In the context of .NET MAUI with Blazor, the standard way to include Blazor components is using AddMauiBlazorWebView.
MainProgram.cs should be like below:
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                });

            builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

#if DEBUG
            builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }

The namespace of NavigationManager should be:

For how to move the Blazor Server App to MAUI Hybrid Blazor app, you need simply follow the steps:

Move the pages/components to common razor class library
Create MAUI Blazor Hybrid Project
Reuse the common razor class library in MAUI and Blazor.

More details refer to the official doc:
Build a .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid app with a Blazor Web App
Host a Blazor web app in a .NET MAUI app using BlazorWebView

Unfortunately, I've done all steps you post, but result is the same. Now trying to catch this exception to understand, where it actually raise.

Hi @Electrionics, it still not working, suggest you can share the repo with us for better debugging(be sure do not contain any sensitive message in the repo).

Hi, I removed this lines due to conflicts in service collection and added custom AuthenticationStateProvider - now it works.
